# How to take arguments in python 3 like myscript.py -i input.txt?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, args

I want my script to take args like:

```
python myscript.py -i input.fastq -q 23 -l 30 -o outfile.fastq
```

not like

python myscript.py input.fastq 23 30 outfile.fastq

Is there any package available to do this in python?

Comment: Yes, the package is named `argparse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use argparse for this:

For example python myscript.py -s customscriptvalue

```
    import argparse

   # Parse arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script options')  
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--script', help='Custom Script to execute', default=None)
    result = parser.parse_args()

    # Treat Arguments in your script
    arguments = dict(result._get_kwargs())
    if arguments['script'] is not None:
        scriptMode = True
        scriptPath = arguments['script']
```

See 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: For the above script (which i didn't change much) I got the output as
takeargs() -i --infile.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-37-7dfeb670a5d3>", line 1, in <module>
   

 takeargs() -i --infile.txt

NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: Not sure to understand how you are using it, which command line do you use to start this script ? yourscript.py -i file.txt should work, but why are you using "-i --" ? Can you provide the edited code and how you want to run it ?

Comment: `import argparse 
def takeargs(): 
 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script options', prefix_chars='-+') 
 parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='Custom Script to execute', default=None) 
 result = parser.parse_args() # Treat Arguments in your script 
 arguments = dict(result._get_kwargs()) if arguments['input'] is not None: 
  scriptMode = True 
  scriptPath = arguments['script'] 
  print(scriptPath)`

Comment: I'm using Spyder ide and running the script in the inbuilt IPython console in spyder

Comment: `import argparse
def takeargs():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script options',prefix_chars='-+')  
    parser.add_argument('-i','--input', type=str, dest='inputFilename')
    arguments=parser.parse_args()
    # Treat Arguments in your script
    if arguments.inputFilename is not None:
        print(arguments.inputFilename)`

Comment: this is my new code and when i run it I am getting 
`takeargs() -input -infile.txt

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'method'`

Comment: what is the cli input for the code you provided above?

Comment: Your current code works fine, but you're trying to pass arguments from inside the IPython console: "takesargs()  -input -infile.txt" will NOT work, as it's interpreted as Python. This kind of program/script arguments needs to be passed on new Python interpreter/script start and not from inside an already running one like you do. Saving your current script (add a call to takeargs() at the end of the file) and calling it from cli "python yourscript.py -i infile.txt" will works fine and print the input filename. (Use -i or --input, not -input, also don't use "-infile.txt" but only "infile.txt")

Comment: No prob', glad it helped !